# Web - iOS low power mode video playback

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, wordpress

Long story short:
Working on a website that has a video set as background and it autoplays. On iOS if "Low Power Mode" is activated the video doesn't play. Don't have an issue with that, but a huge "Play" icon appears on the video. Tried a lot of CSS to hide that button, couldn't manage. Tried various JavaScript solutions to force the video to play, didn't work. Added event listener on the video with "suspend" but it always triggers so I can't use that either to remove the video.

Only idea I have at this point is to detect device and if it's iOS to just hide the video and display a picture but this means that even devices that would play the video won't play it.

Anybody has any solutions for this? Either to bypass the "Low Power Mode" or to hide that "Play" icon?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with a full page web app that utilises the camera. I was able to solve it by removing the `autoplay` property on the video element, and instead playing the video manually when a suspend event is fired:

```js
const handlePlayVideo = (e) => {
  if (e.currentTarget.readyState >= 0) {
    e.currentTarget.play(); // this returns a promise and thus is awaitable if need be
  }
};
```

```html
<video
  muted={true}
  playsInline={true}
  controls={false}
  preload="none"
  onSuspend={handlePlayVideo}
  onLoadedMetadata={handlePlayVideo}
/>
```

Note that `readyState` has [5 state possibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState), you may need to be more specific for a preloaded video when compared to a camera stream.

Just note if you fire it twice (like in my example `onLoadedMetaData` and `onSuspend`) you may get an aborted log in the browser console if both fire close together. You can catch this using the promise on the play function (i.e. `play().catch()`).

Comment: There may be another way to solve the abort log issue but the log wasn't a big issue for us - although if you find an alternate solution I'm all ears :)